# Efficient Querying for common substrings

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a representation of an object being for example
`SubObjects`: `H1`,`H2`,`F1`,`F2`
where each of the `H` anf `F` represent a specific smaller object. I wish to query easily to check all the representations which have 3 of the subobject in common 
eg `H1,H4,F1,F2`  would be returned back, even `H1,H2,F1,F5`. when i query for Objects which have 3 parts of the string representation in common for `H1`,`H2`,`F1`,`F2`.

The string position is important therefore `H2`,`H1`,`F1`,`F2` is different from `H1`,`H2`,`F1`,`F2`.

A brute force plan of action is not possible as I have thousands of such strings to compare. Was thinking of some way hacking round the problem by the use of suffix trees.

Is there any more efficient data structure which i can use to solve the problem?

Comment: Do their positions need to match to, or only values? For example A X C D and A C Y D have 3 matching elements, or 2?

Comment: indeed position does matter sorry for not listing it down

Comment: what's the maximum number of objects in the universe of smaller objects? how many small objects in the longest object representation?

Comment: @DilumRanatunga the maximum number of H's or F's id defined by myself but each H object and F has a specific unique id

Comment: `each H object and F has a specific unique id` If you use map (4 of them), I think you can do this in O(1) or O(log n). If those H and F objects are reused between different SubObjects, then the complexity will be higher, depending on how frequently H and F are reused.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes the subobjects can be reused in different orders and with different subobjects. Can you explain to me what do you mean by map?

Comment: @AdrianDeBarro: Map abstract data structure is used to maintain key-value mapping, usually implemented with tree data structure or hashing.

Comment: @nhahtdh My thinking if no  better solution comes up is to use suffix trees to represent  all the String objects, But i dont know if there is a better and specfic solution.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga the length of sequence of small objects is equal to 4 and it is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i stated in my question i resorted to use suffix trees. Such trees could let me query the tree really rapidly for particular substrings and get back all the objects which contain that particular substring. I dont know if a better solution exists but suffix trees worked well for my problem.
[suffix trees:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)